# wifi.Rssi - conversion from char* to uint8_t

Tags: c++, arduino, wifi, rssi

The error was `'invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]'`. I am trying to get rssi from a network using ssid without connecting to it directly.

```
char ssid[]="GreenNET";
void updateRSSI(){
  rssi = WiFi.RSSI(ssid);
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.print(" dBm");
  Serial.println();
}
```

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiRSSI

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh how to convert char* to uint8_t

Comment: [Let me google that for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+convert+char*+to+uint8_t&oq=how+to+convert+char*+to+uint8_t&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WiFi.RSSI` takes a network index, not an SSID string:

```
char ssid[] = "GreenNET"
uint8_t available_networks = WiFi.scanNetworks();
for (uint8_t net = 0; net < available_networks; ++net)
{
  if (strcmp(WiFi.SSID(net), ssid) == 0)
  {
    rssi = WiFi.RSSI(net);
    Serial.print(rssi);
    Serial.print(" dBm");
    Serial.println();
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: except there should be rssi = WiFi.SSID(net); but it works thank you!

Comment: @hig: `rssi = WiFi.SSID(net);` - you sure about that? I don't follow.